# Ajax retrieve Json string but can not loop the success data as object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, d3.js

My project is to draw grahp with d3.js. I found some php code which is definitely what I want. But I am working with c# and vs. So I am converting it into asp.net. First I want to write some hardcode data sample and draw image using d3.js. as well as a javascript code from that php project. Now I have a server side webmethod which return json string. The parameter dataSample is a Dictionary type. It looks like below and does not have any error.

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSample);

In frontend I am using ajax to retrieve data.

```
 <script>  
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Map.aspx/read_data',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: "{ }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                d3.json("", function (data) {    
                    graph.data = response.d;
                    drawGraph();
                });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Wwoops something went wrong !");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Ajax call is successfully done and Console log displays graph.data which is response.d like below

```
{"DSO":{"name":"DSO","type":"group0","depends":["BPR","Transmission Company","Government"],"dependedOnBy":["TSO","Transmission Company"],"docs":""},"TSO":{"name":"TSO","type":"group1","depends":["BPR","DSO","Producer Secondary Energy","Government"],"dependedOnBy":["Producer Secondary Energy"],"docs":""}}
```

Then I want to loop each json object so I can tell drawGraph() to draw node for each object, for example:

```
for (var name in graph.data) {
        var obj = graph.data[name];
        console.log("name: " + name + "object: " + obj);
```

My problem is console.log("name: " + name + "object: " + obj) is not output each object in Json. It loops everyletter rather than the single object.

The incorrent console.log output is
[image]

I want to ouput the object rather than this.

Comment: The data is probably still a JSON string and not an object yet, so try parsing it. Be careful with for in.

Comment: Also, your `ajax` call is strange.  You don't need both the `$.ajax(` and `d3.json`, these are both methods for making that call and you can remove the `d3.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need to parse json to loop it. Do a proper for loop using the parsed variable.   

<script>  
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Map.aspx/read_data',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: "{ }",
            // remove this line
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                parsedobj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                // do your for loop here
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Wwoops something went wrong !");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi I parsed Json string to object. It works great now. But why I have to remove dataType: "json"?

Answer (score 0):

As @shilly did correctly suggest, you're looping a JSON...
This should be sufficient:

```
var graphDataObject = JSON.parse(graph.data);

for (var name in graphDataObject) {
    var obj = graphDataObject[name];
    console.log("name: " + name + " object: " + obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to JSON.parse string as json and then loop the json object.

Example:

```
<script>
var r = JSON.parse('{"DSO":{"name":"DSO","type":"group0","depends":["BPR","Transmission Company","Government"],"dependedOnBy":["TSO","Transmission Company"],"docs":""},"TSO":{"name":"TSO","type":"group1","depends":["BPR","DSO","Producer Secondary Energy","Government"],"dependedOnBy":["Producer Secondary Energy"],"docs":""}}');

for (var g in r) {
     for (var c in r[g]) {
            console.log(r[g]['name']);
    }

}       
</script>
```